# sfml error when trying to draw a map of sprites

Tags: c++, dictionary, sfml

i have a class which creates a tiled map, but i've got an error with the virtual void draw function :

```
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        states.transform *= getTransform();

        for (int k = 0; k < m_layers ; ++k)
        {
            for (int i = minimum.x; i < maximum.x && i < m_width; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = minimum.y; j < maximum.y && j < m_height; ++j)
                {
                    target.draw(m_map[m_width*(j+k*m_height)+(i+k*m_width)].block, states);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And i've got this error :

```
error: passing 'const std::map<int, carte>' as 'this' argument of 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = carte; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, carte> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = carte; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
```

I have no idea how to fix this, can you help me please :(

If you wonder what "carte" means it's "map" in french. The carte struct has 3 members: an int (data), a sprite ("block") , and a bool (for collisions)

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your draw function is declared `const`. That means you are not allowed to change the object it is called upon. Your map is part of this object and therefore is not allowed to change either.  Now you wonder what this means, because your map does not change, right? Well, the compiler does not know this. You are calling `operator[]` on your map and that is declared as non-const. In other words: you call a method on your map that can *potentially* change it and your compiler complains that you are *not allowed* to do so.

```
const sf::Drawable& d = m_map.at(m_width*(j+k*m_height)+(i+k*m_width)).block;
target.draw(d, states);
```

This will call a method on the map that is *guaranteed to not change it*.

Answer (score 1):

`error: passing 'const std::map<int, carte>'`

Seems like your map is `const`, hence you cannot use `operator[]` on it (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814909/call-size-of-const-mapstring-vectorint-cause-error) question for example). You have two choices : remove the constness, or use the [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) method to access your elements.

Comment: My map is not const, it's my draw function who is. See nvoigt's answer.

Comment: Right, misread a little bit ! Hopefully my answer is still nearly valid.