# call size() of const map<string,vector<int> > cause error

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
  void example(const map<string, vector<int> > & num);

  int main()
  {
      map<string, vector<int> >num;

      num["A"].push_back(1);
      example(num);

      return 0;
  }

  void example(const map<string, vector<int> > & num)
  {
      cout <<  num["A"].size() << endl;
  }
```

i think the size() did not change the value of num, but why it cause error when complie it?
it's ok when i removed the keyword const in the example function.

Comment: It's because `num["A"]` is a non const operation on `std::map`.

Comment: There is an alternative in C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13902825/893693

Comment: @bamboon: Oh, thank god! And, apparently, you've told me about this before...

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the call to `size()`. The problem is using `operator[]()` on a `const` map: if the key doesn't exist, the subscript operator would insert the key and, hence, modify the map. To do so, the `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>` can't be `const`, of course.

If you just want to access the values you'll need to use `find()` directly:

```
void example(std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> const& num) {
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>::const_iterator it(num.find("A"));
    if (it != num.end()) {
        std::cout << it->second.size() << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No key 'A` in the map\n";
    }
}
```

... or you can use `at()` which will throw an exception when accessing a key which isn't present on a non-`const` map (thanks to bamboon for pointing at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902742/why-does-stdmap-not-have-a-const-accessor/13902825#13902825) question):

```
void example(std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> const& num) {
    std::cout << num["A"].size() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: And, yes, it's horrific.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that operator [] is not defined for const objects of type std::map. Here are declarations of the operator

```
T& operator[](const key_type& x);
T& operator[](key_type&& x);
```

As you see the qualifier const after the closing parenthesis of the parameter list is absent.  However member function at is defined for const objects (see the second declaration)

```
T& at(const key_type& x);
const T& at(const key_type& x) const;.
```

So instead of the subscript operator you must use member function at.

Answer (score 0):

The function `num` doesn't know that there is a key `"A"` already added in another function and, if there weren't one, `num["A"]` would add it. Therefore, to use `[]`, the map operand cannot be `const`.

In short, it's not `size()`'s fault.

Answer (score 0):

Others pointed out what's the problem. What you could do now is e.g.

```
  void example(const map<string, vector<int> > & num)
  {
      cout <<  num.at("A").size() << endl;
  }
```

which would be a little bit slower.

Comment: Why would it be slower ?

Comment: Because this function performs range checks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269809/stdvectorat-vs-operator-surprising-results-5-to-10-times-slower-f

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` also needs some more logic and checks because it might need to construct the element.

Comment: @ScepticalJule: I am afraid you did not understand how `at` works on a **map**. There is no concept of range-check on a map: since this is an access by key both `[]` and `at` have to search for the key and decide what to do depending on its presence or absence anyway. Therefore, it is **unlikely** to be slower when the key is present. In its absence... well the two of them do things that are so different it matters little which is slower.